# title tag function

Tags: customization, urls, tags, title

I am using a function to display the URL on title tag, I coded this function which works properly but I would like to customize it more further.

```
function title_tag()
{
$a = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$b = strtoupper($a);
$c = str_replace('-', ' ', $b);
$d = str_replace('/', ' - ', $c);

$e = substr($d, 2);
return $e;
}
```

This function will display the url on title after inserting this code in title tag.

```
<title><?php echo title_tag(); ?></title>
```

The current code is displaying the title in this format, 
my title of website:

***STANFORD UNIVERSITY - MBA IN CALIFORNIA - MBA -***

But I want to display it in this format, just the change in punctuations

***STANFORD UNIVERSITY - MBA IN CALIFORNIA, MBA -***

Just a comma as separator in between
How can I have this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function title_tag () {

    // 0. uppercase string
    $str = strtoupper ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

    // 1. remove trailing and init slash
    $str = trim ( $str , '/' );

    // 2. add search and replace chars; 
    // two array, with same element size, 
    // 1. element of search array will be replaced
    // with the first element of replace array
    $search = array (
        '-',
        '/'
    );

    $replace = array (
        ' ',
        ' - '
    );

    // 3. replace the chars
    $str = str_replace( $search , $replace , $str );

    // 4. replace the last occurance of - for ,
    // $pos finds the position of the last occurance
    // and fortunately, PHP strings can be manipulated 
    // as arrays, so replace the array element with the
    // character
    $pos = strrpos ( $str , '-' );
    $str{$pos} = ',';

    // you're ready
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: hey this really worked and solved my problem, thanks for your help

Comment: the trick was with the trim function, to replace all unwanted / chars, from both the begining and the end of the query string, so you could be sure your want to replace the last - char